# Ask definition of Riemann integral

Tags: integration, analysis

Let $[a,b]$ be an interval and $f$ a function with domain $[a,b]$. We say that the Riemann sums of $f$ tend to a limit $l$ as $m(P)$ tends to $0$ if, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that, if $P$ is any partition of $[a,b]$ with $m(P) < \delta$, then $|R(f,P)-l| < \epsilon$ for every choice of $s_j \in I_j$.

My question is, I don't know how it is incarnated "as $m(P)$ tends to $0$" in this definition?

Source: Real Analysis and Foundations,
Book by Steven G. Krantz

Comment: What's your question? Are you asking what about the correspondence between the first part of the definition (which uses some intuitively understandable words) and the second part (which uses formal language)?

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz my question is this definition just says $m(P) < \delta$, it didn't necessarily mean $m(P)$ goes to 0, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I can address the underlying confusion. Consider the definition of the limit:

> **Definition.** We say that $f(x)$ tends to a limit $g$ as $x$ tends to $x_0$ if, for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that, if $x$ is any point with $|x-x_0| < \delta$, then $|f(x)-f(x_0)| < \varepsilon$

Do you have the same question here?

The point is, the first part (*$f(x)$ tends to a limit $g$ as $x$ tends to $x_0$*) is the thing we're defining right now, so it wouldn't make much sense to say that *there's no $x \to x_0$ is the second part*.

The same goes for the Riemann integral. Before encountering the definition, we don't have any knowledge of what $m(P) \to 0$ might mean (supposedly), so we should accept the words *the Riemann sums of $f$ tend to a limit $l$ as $m(P)$ tends to $0$* as they are. The second part explains the actual meaning.

Answer (score 0):

The interval $[a,b]$ is partitioned as $a = x_0 < x_1 < \ldots < x_{n-1} < x_n = b$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$. In short this partition is denoted by $P$ and $m(P)$ denotes the length of its largest sub-interval. The idea is that, if the largest sub-interval goes to $0$ in length, so must all the others. If the function is Riemann integrable we might write something like
$$ L  := \lim _{m(P) \to 0} \sum f(x_i)\Delta_i =:  \lim _{m(P)\to 0}R(f,P)  $$
where $x_i$ are the knots and $\Delta _i := x_{i}-x_{i-1}$ i.e the length of the respective sub-interval.

---

So by definition of limit, for every $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $m(P)<\delta$ implies $|R(f,P)-L|<\varepsilon$.

---

The limit is taken as $n\to\infty$ i.e the size of a partition grows. Hence, again by definition, at some point, the size of the partition is big enough to guarantee $m(P)<\delta$.

Comment: Please go back to my original definition by using $\epsilon, \delta$. I don't know how that definition reflects the m(P) goes to 0.

Comment: I know. But this just says $m(P) < \delta$, it didn't necessarily mean $m(P)$ goes to 0, right?

Comment: The limit is taken as $n\to\infty$, which implies $m(P) \to 0$. It's just abuse of notation.