# Ask one step in the proof of Riemann integral

Tags: integration, analysis

Lemma: let $f$ be a function with domain the closed interval $[a,b]$. The Riemann integral $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ exists if and only if, for every $\epsilon >0$, there is a $\delta >0$ such that if $P$ and $P'$ are partitions of $[a,b]$ with $m(P) < \delta$ and $m(P') < \delta_1$, then their common refinement $Q$ has the property that $|R(f,P)-R(f,Q)|<\epsilon$ and $|R(f,P')-R(f,Q)|<\epsilon$.

By the way, here the refinement means the union of all the points of $P$ and $P'$.

Proof: If $f$ is Riemann integrable, then the assertion of the lemma follows immediately from the definition of the integral.

But I have problems to understand the other way.

For the converse, note that $|R(f,P)-R(f,Q)|<\epsilon$ and $|R(f,P')-R(f,Q)|<\epsilon$ certainly implies that, if $\epsilon >0$, then there is a $\delta >0$ such that if $P$ and $P'$ are partitions of $[a,b]$ with $m(P) < \delta$ and $m(P') < \delta$, then $|R(f,P)-R(f,P')|<\epsilon$. (just use the triangle inequality)

Now, for each $\epsilon_j =2^{-j}, j=1,2,...,$, we can choose a $\delta_j >0$ as in $|R(f,P)-R(f,P')|<\epsilon$. Let $S_j$ be the closure of the set {$R(f,P): m(P)<\delta_j$}. By the choice of $\delta_j$, the set $S_j$ is contained in a closed interval of length not greater than $2\epsilon_j$.

**Question:** I don't know how to interpret $S_j$ here.

On the one hand, $\cap_j S_j$ must be nonempty since it is the decreasing intersection of compact sets. On the other hand, the length estimate implies that the intersection must be contained in a closed interval of length 0 --- that is, the intersection is a point. That point is then the limit of the Riemann sums, that is, it is the value of the Riemann integral.

Source: Real Analysis and Foundations,
Book by Steven G. Krantz

Comment: what is you definition of riemann integrable?

Comment: @CSquared https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4196564/ask-definition-of-riemann-integral